# How to write a macro function that uses #ifdef

Tags: c, gcc, macros

it's possible to write something like this?

```
#define ISWINDOWS() (#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) \
                        1 \
                   #elif  \
                        0 \
                  #endif)
```

and then:

```
void foo() {
  if(ISWINDOWS()) {
   // ..
  } else {
   // ...  
 }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `_WIN32` is defined for 64-bit builds?  Your `ISWINDOWS` macro is entirely equivalent to checking just `_WIN32`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: I don't knew about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a macro within a macro. You can do this, but its probably not what you want:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define ISWINDOWS() 1
#elif 
    #define ISWINDOWS() 0
#endif
```

Comment: It probably is what the OP wants. BTW, the parentheses aren't necessary; it makes more sense as `#if ISWINDOWS` rather than `#if ISWINDOWS()`

Comment: Thanks. I had used the () because I was writing a "macro function", but how it's not possible I remove it and I'm using like a variable.